# get version sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my code I have:

```
AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,"myDatabase", null, version);

db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
```

First, I check the connectivity with a function. If it returns true, version will be read from a JSON but if it returns false I can't read this value so I want to open the last version of my database but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: With AdminSQLiteOpenHelper I open the database with a number of version.
If I had already created a database I want its version.

Comment: After `getWritableDatabase()` the version is whatever you requested with the arg you passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper` super ctor.

Comment: ... so what's the problem you're trying to solve by knowing the version number?

Comment: For example, I read the JSON and version is 1 so the database is created. The next time I open my app, imagine I can't read the JSON so the var version is null. That's my problem, I should pass version=1 to AdminSQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [onUpgrade method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade) is meant for that. If you try to instantiate/open your database with a number higher than the current on your existing database, onUpgrade will be called.
From there you can do any model update you might need to. [Here's an example](https://github.com/todoroo/astrid/blob/master/astrid/src/com/todoroo/astrid/dao/Database.java#L167)

Comment: Yes but my problem is that the value of version is read from a JSON. So, if can't read it, version is null. In that case, I want to open the database with the last version read.

Comment: The only way to do that is to open the "db" file directly and get the version from there. Here's more about the sqlite format if you want to parse it http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html, although it's probably easier if you store the current version somewhere in sharedPreferences.